# Construct two dimensional numpy array from indices and values of a one dimensional array

Tags: python, numpy

Say I've got

```
Y = np.array([2, 0, 1, 1])
```

From this I want to obtain a matrix X with shape  `(len(Y), 3)`. In this particular case, the first row of X should have a one on the second index and zero otherwhise. The second row of X should have a one on the 0 index and zero otherwise. To be explicit:

```
X = np.array([[0, 0, 1], [1, 0, 0], [0, 1, 0], [0, 1, 0]])
```

How do I produce this matrix?
I started with

```
X = np.zeros((Y.shape[0], 3))
```

but then couldn't figure out how to populate/fill in the ones from the list of indices

As always, thanks for your time!

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: Fair enough: edited to explicitly ask the question

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Maybe:

```
>>> Y = np.array([2, 0, 1, 1])
>>> X = np.zeros((len(Y), 3))
>>> X[np.arange(len(Y)), Y] = 1
>>> X
array([[ 0.,  0.,  1.],
       [ 1.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  1.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  1.,  0.]])
```

Answer (score 3):

To give a one-liner alternative to DSM's perfectly good answer:

```
>>> Y = np.array([2, 0, 1, 1])
>>> np.arange(3) == Y[:, np.newaxis]
array([[False, False,  True],
       [ True, False, False],
       [False,  True, False],
       [False,  True, False]], dtype=bool)
```

Comment: I'd throw in a `*1` or an `.astype(int)`, but +1.

Comment: @DSM Your code is already very significantly faster than this without the type conversion...

Answer (score 1):

```
Y = np.array([2, 0, 1, 1])
new_array = np.zeros((len(Y),3))
for i in range(len(Y)):
    new_array[i,Y[i]] = 1
```

I think ... i dont think there is an easier way (but i might be wrong)

Comment: `np.zeros((len(Y), 3))`.  Also may want to specify `dtype=np.int` as example is showing integers.

Comment: DSM comes through with a better answer :P

Comment: Thanks! In case anyone is interested, I timed @JoranBeasley's and DSM's answer with a 10000 by 3 array and the vectorising gives 744 µs per loop  over 11.8 ms per loop