# Numpy: Set 1 element of each row based on a column index array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

Suppose I have the following arrays:

```
a = np.zeros([4,3])
b = np.asarray([0,1,2,1])
```

Now how can I set an element on each row in array a to 1 based on the column index indicated by array b? What I need is an array c which looks like below:

```
[[ 1.  0.  0.]
 [ 0.  1.  0.]
 [ 0.  0.  1.]
 [ 0.  1.  0.]]
```

Alternatively, is there a way to directly convert array b to array c?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is a job for [advanced indexing](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.indexing.html):

```
a[np.arange(a.shape[0]), b] = 1
```

For arrays `A`, `I`, and `J` where `I` and `J` have integer dtype and identical shape, `A[I, J]` selects all entries `A[I[n], J[n]]` of `A`. The assignment then sets these entries to `1`.

Comment: Do you think this Q is close enough to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18968660/construct-two-dimensional-numpy-array-from-indices-and-values-of-a-one-dimension) to close as dup?  Our answers are similar, and Divakar and Jaime's are similar.

Comment: @DSM: Yeah, that looks like a reasonable dupe target.

Comment: Thanks user2357112. This is exactly what I wanted. @DSM, just wondering how you could find the other question so quickly? I did try to search for a while but couldn't find a similar question.

Comment: @Allen: It's probably easier for him to remember that question since he answered it.

Comment: oh, that makes sense. now. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`NumPy broadcasting`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.broadcasting.html) to directly get `c` from `b` by using `max` of `b` as the number of columns in the output array, like so -

```
(b[:,None] == np.arange(b.max()+1)).astype(float)
```

Sample run -

```
In [484]: b
Out[484]: array([0, 1, 2, 1])

In [485]: (b[:,None] == np.arange(b.max()+1)).astype(float)
Out[485]: 
array([[ 1.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  1.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  1.],
       [ 0.,  1.,  0.]])
```